# Error while running php artisan serve command on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, serve

I am having issues with `php artisan serve` command. I am working on one Laravel project and when I access the folder from browser it is working fine but when I run the `php artisan serve` command it shows me the following error:

> Warning:
>   require(E:\xampp\htdocs\www\LFS\public../vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\www\LFS\public\index.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'E:\xampp\htdocs\www\LFS\public../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='E:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\www\LFS\public\index.php on line 24

I am new to Laravel please let me know where I am going wrong.

I have checked the code in the **public/index.php** file below is my code. I guess everything is fine I just copy-paste the same **index.php** file on my root folder.

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I want that the project can be directly accessible from the browser and should also run on the `php artisan serve` command.

Comment: did you run composer install? Also there is no need to put the project into your htdocs folder if you want to use php artisan serve to spin up a server (just in case you dindn't know). And don't copy paste any index.php files somewhere. The laravel "root" folder is the public folder not the project root.

Comment: By default the serve command uses port 8000, and you should access your website at http://localhost:8000. However if you want to use the default http port, use the command `php artisan serve --port 80`.

Comment: yes I have used composer install command and it installs all the packages actually I am building the chat system with pusher and I am using Vue js as well but when I open my console there in the bootstrap.js file I have the same error. because of which I guess my chat system not working real-time. otherwise, everything is fine but I need to reload the page to get the new message.

Answer (score 1):

In your project folder, the **vendor folder** is missing so you got this error:

> Warning:
>   require(E:\xampp\htdocs\www\LFS\public../vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory

Just run this command:

```
composer update --no-scripts 
composer update
```

With this command, you will re-create the vendor folder in your project

Comment: I have the vendor folder in my project I have run composer update command before and it creates a vendor folder on my root of the project.